# Issue with finding out a percentage from the average in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Before I introduce my issue, I must specify that I am a beginner with SQL and Postgres.

I've made a database in Postgres, as a part of a project and I need to interrogate it. The database is about a firm which sells fertilizer. 
 One of the request is that I need to write a query that will return the Stores with Sales of 25% of the average of the total sales.
I have found out the average of the Sales by using the following query:

```
SELECT StoreID
FROM   Sales 
WHERE  Price < (SELECT ROUND(AVG(Price)) FROM Sales);
```

Now, I don't know what should I put in the query to get the result.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Your request seems a bit ambiguous to me... can you add sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean sales with price below 25% of the average:

```
select storeid
from (
    select storeid, price, avg(price) over() as avg_price
    from   sales 
) s
where  price < 0.25 * avg_price
```

Comment: Could you tell me please what does the "s" before the WHERE statement means exactly?

Comment: @Liviu It is an alias for the subquery